# Dynamic formula or vba to offset a vertical list by one, and move the bottom of the list to the top?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Here is what I am trying to do, I have a sheet that has a list of names with no duplicates that varies in length. I would like to have either with a formula or vba sub, to have the next row copy the original list of names and offset it my one, so that the top name on the original is now the last name of the second list. I need to have at the end 10 list where none of the same names are in the same row.

Here is a sample of what I'd like it to look like.

```
ColumnB   ColumnC   ColumnD   ColumnE
Name1     Name2     Name3     Name4
Name2     Name3     Name4     Name1
Name3     Name4     Name1     Name2
Name4     Name1     Name2     Name3
```

Like a game of Sudoku, none of the names in each row or column can have a duplicate.

I am not sure how to best achieve this since as mentioned above the length of the list is a variable. Ideally I'd like to create the first list, then have the other 9 list to auto populate. Any suggestions?

EDIT___________________
@Paul Drye, I get the following results with your formula

```
ColumnB   ColumnC   ColumnD   ColumnE
Name1     Name2     Name3     Name4
Name2     Name3     Name4     Name1
Name3     Name4     Name1     Name1
Name4     Name1     Name1     Name1
```

As you can see, the last two columns start showing an issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  One trick here is to duplicate the list below and then delete `N` entries from the top and `10-N` entries from the bottom where `N` is the column number and 10 is the number of total entries.  This will give 10 entries which effective shift and wraps around at the end.

Comment: The issue is that the number of entries is not constant. I need it to adjust automatically as I will not always be the one using the sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a formula that works regardless of what surrounds your data, you can get the same result using `ROWS`, `COLUMNS`, and `MOD` along with some absolute/relative ranges.

Formula in cell `C2` copied down and over.  Probably looks a little better with a named range.  If you want to see how it generates the numbers, remove `INDEX` and get the counter.

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$11,MOD(ROWS($C$2:C2)+COLUMNS($C$2:C2)-1,COUNTA($B$2:$B$11))+1)
```

**Picture** shows the same result as the other answer

[image: results and formula]

Comment: Works perfectly once I wrapped it in an IF formula to return a blank if the original list has a blank on the same row. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If a formula works, you can get this result simply with

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B3),B$2,B3)
```

in cell `C2`, assuming your data starts in `B2`.  This can then be copied down and over or filled using <kbd>CTRL+R, CTRL+D</kbd> after selecting the whole range of cells to occupy.

If the copy is correct, the formula of cell `K11` is:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(J12),J$2,J12)
```

**Picture** shows the inputs in column B, the rest are this formula

[image: results of formula]

This formula works more or less because of the absolute row reference which ensures that the value from row 2 is used if we are at the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your list begins in A1, try this in B1:

```
=IF(A2="",IF(ISERR(OFFSET(A$1,-1,0)),A$1, A$1),A2)
```

You can then copy this down and across the columns to get your remaining data. The formula has reference issues if you copy it up, or if you copy it more columns to the right than you have pieces of data, but otherwise it does the trick.

Basically it says "Look at the cell one to the left and one down, and give me that unless that cell is blank. In that case, give me the first item in the column instead."

Comment: That half worked. It offsets the the names, until it reaches a "", then it just says FALSE. I have headers in the first row, so the names actually start on B2, so my version of your above formula looked like this in C2 `=IF(B3="",IF(ISERR(OFFSET(B$2,-1,0)),B$2),B3)` am I missing something?

Comment: Why the `ISERR(OFFSET(...))` part?  You can get the same result from `=IF(ISBLANK(B3),B$2,B3)` (using OP starting in `B2`).  Offsetting one row up from `A1` will always form an error.

Comment: You're quite right that something is missing. I've edited the formula in the original answer to include what should have been there.

Comment: Byron, without the ISERR Excel attempts to evaluate the OFFSET in a way that causes an error when the formula is copied into the last cell in each column. That in turn causes the formula as a whole to evaluate to an error rather than returning the correct name. Try the version without the ISERR and see what I mean:

`=IF(A2="",OFFSET(A$1,-1,0),A2)`

 That said, your solution is cleaner than mine, so I recommend it. Make it an answer and I would upvote it.

Comment: It's still not quite right. Please see my edit on my OP.